# Persist a file path of a docker mapped volume on host into database

Tags: docker

What I have: A spring boot application running as/inside a docker container. This application gives an opportunity of uploading files to a directory inside the docker container. I also have specified a volume mapping on the server/host which points to this directory.

What I need: Persist the path of the host directory (docker volume?), which points to the directory inside the docker container, into database in order to refer to it later. How can I do this?

Comment: By passing data from the scope of the host into the scope of the container,  you're smearing the boundary around the container.   I can't come up with a good reason the container would need to know the host's inaccessible volume share path.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC there's no intrinsic way to determine the volume mapping from within the container.

You could achieve this by passing an environment variable to your process and having confidence its value is correct:

```
V=/path/to/src
docker run .... \
--env=V=${V} \
--volume=${V}/path/to/dst \
...
```

Comment: `docker inspect` would probably show it,  but that would only be accessible in the container if the docker socket itself was made available. I like the use of an environment variable to share the location,  and the use in the volume makes sure it's right.

Comment: I think it's a good practice for a process to not assume that it's running in a container (Docker or other). Using the environment addresses this.

Comment: However, exposing host paths that are not accessible from the scope of the container forces this assumption to be made.  The source of the mount has no relevance to the container, as it must be supplied before the container is started.  It should be part of the host-level orchestration, just like pulling the image, and starting it up.